# Store option not working dgrid, works perfect with ondemandgrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I want to use store attribute of Dgrid, i am using below code to make dgrid table but somehow table doesn't get populated with rows.

```
 <script src="dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
   <script>
        require(["dojo/_base/declare","dgrid/Grid","dgrid/Keyboard","dgrid/Selection","dgrid/editor","dgrid/extensions/DnD","dojo/dnd/Source", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/_base/lang"],
                function (declare,Grid,Keyboard,Selection,editor,DnD, DnDSource, Memory, lang){
                    var store = new Memory({
                        data: [
                            { id: 1, firstName: "Jeffrey", lastName: "Andrews", email: "jeffrey@madeupdomain.com" },
                            { id: 2, firstName: "Jenny", lastName: "Saunders", email: "jenny@madeupdomain.com" },
                        ]
                    });
                    var structure = [
                        {field: "lastName", label: "Last Name"},
                        {field: "firstName", label: "First Name"},
                        {field: "email", label: "EMail Address"}
                    ];

                    var grid = new (declare([Grid, Selection, DnD]))({
                                store: store,
                                columns: structure
                            },
                            "gridtable");
                    grid.startup();
                });

    </script>
</head>

<div id="gridtable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The base `List` and `Grid` modules are not designed to be store-aware.  Store awareness is usually inherited from `_StoreMixin`, which `OnDemandList` and the `Pagination` extension inherit.

It's also feasible to make your own extension of `_StoreMixin`; for example, one of the tutorials on [dgrid.io](http://dgrid.io) walks through a [very simple extension to render all data from a store at once](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/single_query/).